# Float spacing on float pages

Tags: spacing, floats

I am writing my thesis, and one of the requirements is that any pages containing only figures or tables must be top-aligned.  An additional requirement is that the spacing between consecutive figures or tables must be the same throughout the document.

By default, when I have two or more tables on a float page they are equally spaced and centered vertically.  In order to achieve top-alignment, I am using:

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother
```

This brings the first float on the float page to the top, but it leaves a large amount of white space between the first and second float.  I would like to specify the distance between floats on float pages so that it is the same as `\floatsep` (i.e., so that the spacing between floats is the same as it would be if the two floats were at the top or bottom of a page).  Is there an equivalent to `\floatsep` for float pages?  Or is there a way to make all floats top-aligned on a float page?

Comment: For future reference: Please provide the community with a foundation to work from in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). We want to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what problem you're experiencing. It'll speed up getting solutions your way and make the problem far more tangible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to setting `\@fptop` and `\@fpbot`, also set `\@fpsep` (to `\floatsep`, which has a default of `12\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@`):

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}% default is 0\p@ \@plus 1fil
\setlength{\@fpsep}{\floatsep}% default is 8\p@ \@plus 2fil
%\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}% default is 0\p@ \@plus 1fil
\makeatother
```

I've also given the defaults used in the LaTeX kernel ([`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help, Werner!  This solved my problem.  A MWE would have been difficult to provide for this case because I am using a custom .cls file that does some strange things to floats.

Comment: @JSchaefer: *Especially* in cases like that, spoon-feeding us information is important. It seems this time my crystal ball paid off. I knew it was worth the 25c I paid for it. :-|